# File Operation for storeing,read and load data,function for newly registred employees

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

1)Create a file for storing employee data.
2) Implement a function to read and load employee data from the file into objects when the application starts (if the file exists).
3)Implement a function to save newly registered employees to the file.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FILE = "C:\\demo\\EVAL.txt";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter EmployeeId");
            int eid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name");
            string fname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Last Name");
            string lname = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Email");
            string emailid = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter DateOfBirth");
            string dobirth = Console.ReadLine();

            Employee employee = new Employee(eid, fname, lname, emailid, dobirth);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Employee Details: Employee Id: {eid}, FIRSTNAME: {fname}, LASTNAME: {lname}, DOB: {dobirth}, EMAIL: {emailid}");

            // JSON SerialiZATION
            string jsonEmployee = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
            //string filename = "C:\\demo\\eval.json";
            //File.WriteAllText(filename, jsonEmployee);
            //Console.WriteLine("Employee JSON Data saved to file: "+filename);


            //XML SERILIZATION
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
            string filepath = "C:\\demo\\eval.xml";
            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Create);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(filestream, employee);
            filestream.Close();
            //Console.WriteLine("Employee  saved to file:" +filepath);


            //fILE OPERATION
            string filename = "C:\\demo\\eval.txt";
           /* string empdata = $"Employee Details: Employee Id: {eid}, FIRSTNAME: {fname}, LASTNAME: {lname}, DOB: {dobirth}, EMAIL: {emailid}";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine(empdata);
            }*/
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File created");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not created");
            }
            }
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried. Edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: I need an above implementation function to read and load employee data from the file into objects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to add desirilization for above code

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried using json. Working with json is a bit easier than working with xml in c# in my opinion.

To get you started read through the Microsoft Documentation for [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0) and [deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/deserialization?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

This is all you need.

Specifically those lines:

```cs
//Serialize
string fileName = "WeatherForecast.json"; 
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonString);

//Deserialize
string fileName = "WeatherForecast.json";
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
WeatherForecast weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString)!;
```

Replace `WeatherForecast` with `Employee` or even `List<Employee>`